# python virtualenv(wrapper) + uwsgi + nginx (YET AGAIN)

Tags: python, virtualenv, uwsgi, virtualenvwrapper

Ok, I know there are loads of `virtualenv + uwsgi + nginx` articles out there, I've read about 50 of them (I have *not* fully read the uWSGI documentation).

My question:

Why do none of these options actually `activate` the virtualenv I am asking it to do?

```
[uwsgi]
home = <path to python3 venv>
venv = <path to python3 venv>
virtualenv = <path to python3 venv>
```

However I try, I can't start `uwsgi`(installed and working) from the default `python2.7`, and have it read the `uwsgi.ini`, `activate` the `virtualenv`, and fire up my `django`-project. `uwsgi` is also installed on the `virtualenv`.

All other stuff is in place (users, groups and permissions), and working.

FAIL: Starting with *no* `virtualenv` active:

```
$> uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from uwsgi.ini
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.9 (64bit) on [Fri Feb 13 14:48:03 2015] ***
compiled with version: 4.8.2 on 20 January 2015 14:01:30
os: Linux-3.13.0-43-generic #72-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 8 19:35:06 UTC 2014
nodename: intergate.io
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /www/django/intergate_io
writing pidfile to /www/django/intergate_io/run/project-master.pid
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
chdir() to /www/django/intergate_io
your processes number limit is 3750
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: enabled
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /www/django/intergate_io/run/socket.sock fd 3
Python version: 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 23:03:41)  [GCC 4.8.2]
Set PythonHome to /opt/vEnvs3/django/
ImportError: No module named site
```

Sucess: Activating `virtualenv`, and starting:

```
$> workon django
(django) $> uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.9 (64bit) on [Fri Feb 13 14:49:42 2015] ***
compiled with version: 4.8.2 on 13 February 2015 06:07:54
os: Linux-3.13.0-43-generic #72-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 8 19:35:06 UTC 2014
nodename: intergate.io
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /www/django/intergate_io
writing pidfile to /www/django/intergate_io/run/project-master.pid
detected binary path: /opt/vEnvs3/django/bin/uwsgi
chdir() to /www/django/intergate_io
your processes number limit is 3750
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: enabled
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /www/django/intergate_io/run/socket.sock fd 3
Python version: 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:08:40)  [GCC 4.8.2]
Set PythonHome to /opt/vEnvs3/django/
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0xe7fc00
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 218280 bytes (213 KB) for 2 cores
*** Operational MODE: preforking ***
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 1 seconds on interpreter 0xe7fc00 pid: 2682 (default app)
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 2682)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 2683, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 2684, cores: 1)
```

Comment: You should probably mention in your question's title, text and tags that it's about python 3. That's a pretty big difference. Also the same setup with 2.7 works flawlessly in my experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case you seem to be launching some kind of global (maybe one installed with `sudo pip`) uwsgi, as indicated by output:

```
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
```

It may be missing python3 plugin to properly switch environments, and in general I found it is always simpler to use uwsgi from virtualenv - it just works more often. Really, don't bother trying to make system-wide work, use your own. You will need to put a full path in one more config, but that's hardly a problem. Just launch `/path/to/your/venv/bin/uwsgi` instead of just `uwsgi`.

Comment: Nice! So I can just run the `venv-uwsgi` directly and it will start up with that `venv`. Seems to work. Thnx.

Comment: Most of the docs I  read made it seem that the system wide uwsgi would be able to switch to a venv based on the .ini settings. This is not true,  then?

Comment: Like I said, probably a plugin issue, but who knows? All in all uwsgi docs and overall ease of setup (especially in corner cases and unusual setups) is not its strong suit. But once you have set it up, it is rock-solid and generally won't break for no reason.