# Internal Server Error for Django with uwsgi / nginx on Debian8.7

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, nginx, uwsgi

I'm pretty beginner in server technologies and I'm struggling to deploy a Django app to Debian8 server.
I've been following : [this tutorial](https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/nginx/deploy-django-applications-using-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) but I couldn't start uWSGI service so I followed [this recommendation](https://serverfault.com/questions/775965/wiring-uwsgi-to-work-with-django-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04) and switched to `systemd`.
Then I've been able to run my app in development mode on port `:8000` but couldn't load it in browser.

The logs say: `no python application found, check your startup logs for errors`

Above this note in logs it complains on not being able load `whitenoise` module:

```
File "./testdjango/wsgi.py", line 35, in <module>
    from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise
```

which means (if I'm not mistaken) it doesn't load virtual environment.

**updated**

It doesn't work anymore if I run uwsgi terminal command
`uwsgi --http :8000 --chdir /home/djangouser/testdjango --module testdjango.wsgi:application --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=testdjango.settings --home /home/djangouser/Env/myapp_env`

I have no ideas why it happens and I'd appreciate any help or guide.

I did search before I posted this question here and in fact I've been trying many different solutions without success for the last three days. Because of that my files seems to be messy now. My apologies for that.

I use django 1.8, virtualenvvrapper, sudo user named djangouser and the folder structure on the server looks like this:

```html
-home
  |
  |--djangouser
    |
    |--Env
    |   |--myapp_env
    |
    |--testdjango
       |
       |-- app
       |-- testdjango
       |     |
       |     |-- wsgi.py
       |     |-- settings.py
       |
       |-- uwsgi.ini
       |-- manage.py
```

`/etc/uwsgi/sites/testdjango.ini` file:

```
[uwsgi]
project = testdjango
base = /home/djangouser

chdir = %(base)/%(project)
home = %(base)/Env/myapp_env
module = %(project).wsgi:application
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=%(project).settings

master = true
processes = 5

socket = %(base)/%(project)/%(project).sock
chmod-socket = 666
vacuum = true
```

`/etc/systemd/system/uwsgi.service` file:

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI Emperor service
After=syslog.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites

Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
StandardError=syslog
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`/etc/nginx/sites-available/testdjango` file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name xx.xx.xx.xx myapp.com www.myapp.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/djangouser/testdjango/static/;
    }

    location /media  {
        root /home/djangouser/testdjango/media/;
    }

    location / {
        include         uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass      unix:/home/djangouser/testdjango/testdjango.sock;
    }
}
```

`wsgi.py` file:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "testdjango.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(get_wsgi_application())
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
uwsgi --http :8000 --chdir /home/djangouser/testdjango --module testdjango.wsgi:application --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=testdjango.settings --home /home/djangouser/Env/myapp_env
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.15 (64bit) on [Wed Apr  5 14:48:34 2017] ***
compiled with version: 4.9.2 on 04 April 2017 17:12:38
os: Linux-4.9.7-x86_64-linode80 #2 SMP Thu Feb 2 15:43:55 EST 2017
nodename: xxonexx
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /home/djangouser/Env/myapp_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
chdir() to /home/djangouser/testdjango
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your processes number limit is 3934
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 65536
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uWSGI http bound on :8000 fd 4
spawned uWSGI http 1 (pid: 5293)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:36933 (port auto-assigned) fd 3
Python version: 2.7.9 (default, Jun 29 2016, 13:11:10)  [GCC 4.9.2]
Set PythonHome to /home/djangouser/Env/myapp_env
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x12036b0
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 72760 bytes (71 KB) for 1 cores
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
HI!
Djangomode is: 
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./testdjango/wsgi.py", line 38, in <module>
    from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise
  File "/home/djangouser/Env/myapp_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/whitenoise/django.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import staticfiles_storage
  File "/home/djangouser/Env/myapp_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.core.cache import (
  File "/home/djangouser/Env/myapp_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/cache/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    if DEFAULT_CACHE_ALIAS not in settings.CACHES:
  File "/home/djangouser/Env/myapp_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/djangouser/Env/myapp_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/djangouser/Env/myapp_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "./testdjango/settings.py", line 59, in <module>
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = os.getenv('ALLOWED_HOSTS').split(',')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (and the only) (pid: 5292, cores: 1)
```

Comment: Could you show us your uwsgi logs? Also, if you're willing to set everything up from scratch again, I wrote [a quick guide](https://gist.github.com/airstrike/3b513e3c24e5c6f91f1fb8f71947a033) for my own future reference. Just change 'moco' everywhere to your own project name. Should work in any clean ubuntu/debian install and builds a perfectly clean uwsgi / nginx / django / psql stack.

Comment: Also, there's a 99% chance you're dealing with a PATH issue or lack of appropriate permissions.

Comment: Thank you @andre-terra, I've just posted the logs. It just doesn't load venvwrapper environment.
I agree about PATH. If I won't fix current state of uwsgi now, it seems that I'll have to start from scratch once again. I'll follow your instruction in that case for sure.

Comment: it seems like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28507705/python-virtualenvwrapper-uwsgi-nginx-yet-again) might be a key to the solution. I'm not sure how to run "venv-uwsgi" though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after four days of struggle I found where the problem was.
After giving this problem a fresh start for the 3rd time and examining the error messages on the server I figured out that I should import my environmental vars into uwsgi ini-file.
After doing that, errors in uwsgi.log disappeared and the app started working as intended.

I really hope this answer will save somebody time in the future.

Comment: Can you give us an example of how you did that pls

Comment: @Sevenearths yes sure. I added venv vars to `/etc/uwsgi/sites/mysite.ini` like so:

`env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings`
`env = ALLOWED_HOSTS=mysite.com`
`env = DJANGO_MODE=Production`

Answer (score 0):

In production, you need to edit `ALLOWED_HOSTS` in settings.py.

[The official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts) show the following examples:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    '.example.com',  # Allow domain and subdomains
    '.example.com.',  # Also allow FQDN and subdomains
]
```

You should probably follow whatever you have in the beginning of your `/etc/nginx/sites-available/testdjango` file.

The reason you don't see this in development is because that setting gets automatically populated with 'localhost' so it's never empty.

Comment: the thing is that I use thi variable as environmental in postactivate file:
export ALLOWED_HOSTS="example.com"
I also have a bunch of other environmental vars that I'll need.
This is why it's crucial to load venv with uwsgi and this is where I fail :)

Comment: meant to say that I use os.getenv in settings.py

`ALLOWED_HOSTS = os.getenv('ALLOWED_HOSTS').split(',')`

Comment: @user2241956 Have you tried adding a `venv` setting to your uwsgi .ini pointing to the folder where the virtual env resides?

Comment: I've just tried it but it didn't help.
I'm getting the same error if I try to run `uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini` from project root directory

Comment: it works only if I start virtual environment manually by `workon myapp_env`

Comment: I think your service file is incorrect as it refers to the project's settings file when it should actually be a system-wide service

Comment: just updated service's code above since it gives same error. It was initial code actually and then after many tries and experiments it transformed into one you saw before.
It's really frustrating since it seems that all the pieces are there but they aren't working together.

Is it possible that the issue appears because I have installed uWSGI under virtual environment and as sudo on server?

Comment: @user2241956 yes, you should install uwsgi as sudo

Comment: can you repost the logs now that you've changed your service command?